# Open Link in UIWebview not UIShared Application

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, hyperlink

I have been having a rough time trying to open links that a user clicks in a simple web view instead of multitasking and going to safari. It is quite a pain for my users to have to leave the app every time a link is clicked and I know it is probably quite simple but still am having a terrible time making this happen. Here is the code I am using but still when the link is clicked it opens safari.

If anyone can help point me in the right direction I would be greatly appreciative! Thank you!

```
     - (void) handleURL:(NSURL*)url
    {  
    [web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"%@"]]];
    }


    - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest 
*)request  
    navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSLog(@"expected:%d, got:%d", UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked, navigationType);
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication] ;
    return NO;
    }
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {    
   [web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL 
    URLWithString:replyTweetText.text]]];    
    return YES;
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what this bit does:

```
if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication] ;
    return NO;
    }
```

The line `[UIApplication sharedApplication];` creates and returns the singleton application instance. You aren't doing anything with it.

Also, both `if` statements are identical, so only the first will ever be hit and the method returns `NO`. There is no default returned value, which is bad for a non-void function. Try this instead:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    return YES;
}
```